# Group Requests in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

If an application is built with several components, is there a way to have a @Path prefix for resources inside a component?

As an example, let's consider this service for retrieving info about several universities from a city. The components would be schoolA and schoolB.

```
amsterdam-schools.com/schoolA/students/
amsterdam-schools.com/schoolA/teachers/
amsterdam-schools.com/schoolA/teachers/{id}
amsterdam-schools.com/schoolA/teachers/{id}/courses
...

amsterdam-schools.com/schoolB/teachers
amsterdam-schools.com/schoolB/students
...
```

Is it possible to implement somthing like the code below?

```
@Path("/schoolA")
public abstract class SchoolA {
    //  ...
} 

@Path(@SuperPath + "/teachers")
public class TeacherListResource extends SchoolA {

    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("id") Integer teacherId) {
        //  ...
    }

    //  ...
}
```

I know @SuperPath doesn't exist, but what would be the best practice not to write "SchoolA" in every resource class? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy multiple JAX-RS applications with different URIs in one WAR.

You will have to create one `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` subclass per such an application (or use `web.xml` for this purpose).
And you will have to explicitly configure resources in each subclass by overriding the `getClasses` or `getSingletons` method:

```
@Path("first")
public class FirstResource {
    @GET
    public String first() {
        return "first";
    }
}

@ApplicationPath("one")
public class JAXRSConfigurationOne extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(FirstResource.class);
        return resources;
    }
}

@Path("second")
public class SecondResource {
    @GET
    public String first() {
        return "second";
    }
}

@ApplicationPath("two")
public class JAXRSConfigurationTwo extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(SecondResource.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

Both JAX-RS applications become accessible through distinct URIs:

- http://localhost:8080/multiple-roots/one/first
- http://localhost:8080/multiple-roots/two/second

For more details, have a look [here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/multiple_jax_rs_uris_in).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normally if you are using Jersey, for each component you have to define an Application class that extends `javax.ws.rs.coreApplication`. In this class also you will have to define an `@ApplicationPath`.

For instance :

```
@ApplicationPath("/my-base-url-for-my-component")
public class MyComponent extends Application {}
```

All ressources defined in MyComponent will be prefixed with `/my-base-url-for-my-component`.